# C# Trying to get XML inner text for nested node

Tags: c#, xml

I can succesfully load the XMl document and traverse the nodes. Once I get the node that I want, I start setting values. How do I deal with nested nodes?

Here is the xml:

```
<incident>
<id>1234</id>
<number>5678</number>
<name>This is a name</name>
<state>Awaiting Input</state>
<priority>Medium</priority>
<category>
    <id>99999</id>
    <name>Applications</name>
    <default_tags>applications</default_tags>
    <parent_id nil="true" />
    <default_assignee_id nil="true" />
</category>
```

Here is some C#:

```
   id = node.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText;  //works fine
   number = node.SelectSingleNode("number").InnerText;  //works fine

   name = node.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;  //works fine
   descHTML = node.SelectSingleNode("description").InnerText;  //works fine
   desc = node.SelectSingleNode("description_no_html").InnerText;  //works fine
   state = node.SelectSingleNode("state").InnerText;  //works fine
   priority = node.SelectSingleNode("priority").InnerText;  //works fine

   catagoryID = node.SelectSingleNode("category/id").InnerText; // null reference error
   catagoryName = node.SelectSingleNode("category/name").InnerText; // null reference error
   catagoryTags = node.SelectSingleNode("category/default_tags").InnerText; // null reference error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are reading different elements that may or may not exist, use `?.` after the `SelectSingleNode` method. This will ensure you dont get the error `Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an object`.

`?.` in essence checks if there is a value before proceeding to evaluate the next method or proprety.

```
string xml = @"<incident>
<id>1234</id>
<number>5678</number>
<name>This is a name</name>
<state>Awaiting Input</state>
<priority>Medium</priority>
<category>
    <id>99999</id>
    <name>Applications</name>
    <default_tags>applications</default_tags>
    <parent_id nil=""true"" />
    <default_assignee_id nil=""true"" />
</category>
</incident>";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);
        var node = doc.DocumentElement;

        var id = node.SelectSingleNode("id")?.InnerText;  //works fine
       var number = node.SelectSingleNode("number")?.InnerText;  //works fine

       var name = node.SelectSingleNode("name")?.InnerText;  //works fine
       var descHTML = node.SelectSingleNode("description")?.InnerText;  //ERRORS because there is no description.
       var desc = node.SelectSingleNode("description_no_html")?.InnerText;  //works fine
       var state = node.SelectSingleNode("state")?.InnerText;  //works fine
       var priority = node.SelectSingleNode("priority")?.InnerText;  //works fine

       var catagoryID = node.SelectSingleNode("//category/id")?.InnerText; // null reference error
       var catagoryName = node.SelectSingleNode("//category/name")?.InnerText; // null reference error
       var catagoryTags = node.SelectSingleNode("//category/default_tags")?.InnerText; // null reference error

        Console.WriteLine($"name: {name}");
        Console.WriteLine($"descHTML: {descHTML}");
        Console.WriteLine($"desc: {desc}");
        Console.WriteLine($"state: {state}");
        Console.WriteLine($"priority: {priority}");
        Console.WriteLine($"catagoryID: {catagoryID}");
        Console.WriteLine($"catagoryName: {catagoryName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"catagoryTags: {catagoryTags}");
```

**Output it prints out**

```
name: This is a name
descHTML: 
desc: 
state: Awaiting Input
priority: Medium
catagoryID: 99999
catagoryName: Applications
catagoryTags: applications
```

[Code on #dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/n1Yydn)

Comment: I spent hours and hours on this and it was a simple "\\". Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you use the XmlDocument class and CATEGORY NODE is the only item that will have childnodes, so I have this method to go through each element, including subnodes *(I hope this helps someone).*

```
string xml = 
@"<incident>
    <id>1234</id>
    <number>5678</number>
    <name>This is a name</name>
    <state>Awaiting Input</state>
    <priority>Medium</priority>
    <category>
        <id>99999</id>
        <name>Applications</name>
        <default_tags>applications</default_tags>
        <parent_id nil=""true"" />
        <default_assignee_id nil=""true"" />
    </category>
</incident>";

List<String> innerTextNode = new List<string>();
XmlDocument XmlDoc= new XmlDocument();
XmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

XmlElement root = XmlDoc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList nodes = root.ChildNodes;
XmlNodeList childs;

foreach (XmlNode anode in nodes)
{
    // The next is for any NODE that will have childnodes
    // bool havechilds = anode.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlNode>().Any(x => x.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Text)

    if (!anode.LocalName.Equals("category", StringComparison.CurrentCulture))
    {
        // The node is only text, no has childnodes
        // So capturing InnerText
        innerTextNode.Add(anode.InnerText);
    }
    else
    {
        childs = nodo.ChildNodes;
        foreach (XmlNode childone in childs)
        {
            // So capturing InnerText
            innerTextNode.Add(childone.InnerText);
        }
    }
}
```